# Dependency Injection : Unity.GetService does not exist in version 5.8.6

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

In Unity **5.7.3** there was **GetService** method in **UnityContainer** class

```
public class UnityContainer : IUnityContainer, IDisposable, IServiceProvider
{
    public UnityContainer();

    public IUnityContainer Parent { get; }
    public IEnumerable<IContainerRegistration> Registrations { get; }

    public IUnityContainer AddExtension(UnityContainerExtension extension);
    public object BuildUp(Type typeToBuild, object existing, string nameToBuild, params ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides);
    public object Configure(Type configurationInterface);
    public IUnityContainer CreateChildContainer();
    public void Dispose();
    public object GetService(Type serviceType);//here
    public bool IsRegistered(Type type, string name);
    public bool IsTypeRegisteredLocally(Type type, string name);
    public IUnityContainer RegisterInstance(Type registeredType, string name, object instance, LifetimeManager lifetimeManager);
    public IUnityContainer RegisterType(Type typeFrom, Type typeTo, string name, LifetimeManager lifetimeManager, InjectionMember[] injectionMembers);
    public object Resolve(Type typeToBuild, string nameToBuild, params ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides);
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing);
}
```

but in Version **5.8.6** is doesn't seem to exist anymore

```
public class UnityContainer : IUnityContainer, IDisposable
{
    public UnityContainer();

    public IEnumerable<IContainerRegistration> Registrations { get; }
    public IUnityContainer Parent { get; }

    public IUnityContainer AddExtension(UnityContainerExtension extension);
    public object BuildUp(Type typeToBuild, object existing, string nameToBuild, params ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides);
    public object Configure(Type configurationInterface);
    public IUnityContainer CreateChildContainer();
    public void Dispose();
    public bool IsRegistered(Type type, string name);
    public IUnityContainer RegisterInstance(Type registeredType, string name, object instance, LifetimeManager lifetimeManager);
    public IUnityContainer RegisterType(Type typeFrom, Type typeTo, string name, LifetimeManager lifetimeManager, InjectionMember[] injectionMembers);
    public object Resolve(Type typeToBuild, string nameToBuild, params ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides);
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing);
}
```

GetService method seems to be coming from **IServiceProvider** which is in **mscorlib** assembly

Does anyone have information in regard to how can we achieve functionality of GetService in version 5.8.6?

Below is the sample code I was using in version 5.7.3 to get a service in my console app

```
        var fooservice= (FooService)unity.GetService(typeof(IFooService));
```